# Running a Docker container that accept traffic from the host

Tags: apache, centos, docker, dockerfile

I have the following config:
Dockerfile

```
FROM centos  
MAINTAINER Eduar Tua <eduartua@gmail.com>  

RUN yum -y update && yum clean all
RUN yum -y install httpd && yum clean all
RUN echo "Apache works" >> /var/www/html/index.html

EXPOSE 80

ADD run-apache.sh /run-apache.sh
RUN chmod -v +x /run-apache.sh

CMD ["/run-apache.sh"]
```

The run-apache.sh script:

```
#!/bin/bash

rm -rf /run/httpd/* /tmp/httpd*

exec /usr/sbin/apachectl -D FOREGROUND
```

Then I build the image with:

```
sudo docker build --rm -t platzi/httpd .
```

then

```
sudo docker run -d -p 80:80 platzi/httpd
```

After that when I try to run the container accepting connections from the host in the 80 port I get this:

```
67ed31b50133adc7c745308058af3a6586a34ca9ac53299d721449dfa4996657
FATA[0002] Error response from daemon: Cannot start container     67ed31b50133adc7c745308058af3a6586a34ca9ac53299d721449dfa4996657: Error starting userland proxy: listen tcp 0.0.0.0:80: bind: address already in use
```

Any help?

Comment: You say you're doing "`docker run`" and then after that "try[ing] to run the container."  Why are you running it after you already ran it?

Comment: Hey @jwodder it was my mistake to write like that, I got the error after run the container. That' s what I mean.

Comment: Also when I check with `docker ps` There is no container running.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The error seems pretty clear:

> FATA[0002] Error response from daemon: Cannot start container     67ed31b50133adc7c745308058af3a6586a34ca9ac53299d721449dfa4996657: Error starting userland proxy: listen tcp 0.0.0.0:80: bind: address already in use

It says, "address already in use".  This means that something on your system -- probably a web server like Apache -- is already listening on port 80.  You will either need to:

- stop the web server,
- select a different host port in the `-p` argument to `docker run` or
- just drop the `-p` argument.

Because Docker can't set up the requested port forwarding, it does not start the container.

Options (a) and (b) will both allow the container to bind to port 80 on your host.  This is only necessary if you want to access the container from somewhere other than your host.

Option (c) is useful if you only want to access the container from the docker host but do not want to otherwise expose the container on your local network.  In this case, you would use the container ip address as assigned by docker, which you can get by running `docker inspect` and perusing the output, or just running:

```
docker inspect --format '{{ .NetworkSettings.IPAddress }}' container_id
```

Comment: Thanks @larsks The Apache Web server was running on my host system. Could I have Apache running on my host and redirect the traffic to my container? both on port 80.

Comment: You cannot have two things listening on the same port on the same ip address.  If you want your container to be accessible from outside your host on port 80, you will need to assign an additional ip address on your host and then bind the container to that address using the `-p` flag (`-p <host_ip>:<host_port>:<container_port>`).

Comment: Thanks @larsks , stupid question. But your suggestion helps me a lot.

Comment: If this solved things for you, consider marking this answer as "accepted" by clicking the checkmark to the left of the answer.  Thanks!

Comment: Done @larsks , I am a newbie here.

Comment: I am facing the same issue "Error starting userland proxy: listen tcp 0.0.0.0:80: bind: address already in use." I killed the process id and then ran the same command " sudo docker container run --publish 80:80 nginx". Now it is not responding/not executing. I waited for around 30 mins. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 38):

It is saying port 80 is busy ... run this to see who is using port 80

```
sudo netstat -tlnp | grep 80 # sudo apt-get install net-tools # to install netstat

tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1380/nginx -g daemo
tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN      1380/nginx -g daemo
```

scroll to far right to see offending PID of process holding port 80 ... its PID 1380 so lets do a process list to see that pid

```
ps -eaf | grep 1380

root      1380     1  0 11:33 ?        00:00:00 nginx: master process /usr/sbin/nginx -g daemon on; master_process on;
```

so teardown that offending process to free up the port 80

```
sudo kill 1380  # if you know the pid ( 1380 for example )
```

__ or __

```
sudo fuser -k 80/tcp #  just kill whatever pid is using port 80 tcp
```

If after doing above its still saying busy then probably the process which you killed got auto relaunched in which case you need to kill off its watcher however you can walk up the process tree from netstat output to identify this parent process and kill that too

Here is how to identify the parent pid of a given process pid

```
ps -eafww

eve         2720    2718  0 07:56 ?        00:00:00 /usr/share/skypeforlinux/skypeforlinux --type=zygote
```

in above pid is 2720 and its parent will be the next column to right pid 2718 ...  there are commands to show a process tree to visualize these relationships

```
ps -x --forest
```

or

```
pstree  -p
```

with sample output of

```
systemd(1)─┬─ModemManager(887)─┬─{ModemManager}(902)
           │                   └─{ModemManager}(906)
           ├─NetworkManager(790)─┬─{NetworkManager}(872)
           │                     └─{NetworkManager}(877)
           ├─accounts-daemon(781)─┬─{accounts-daemon}(792)
           │                      └─{accounts-daemon}(878)
           ├─acpid(782)
           ├─avahi-daemon(785)───avahi-daemon(841)
           ├─colord(1471)─┬─{colord}(1472)
           │              └─{colord}(1475)
           ├─containerd(891)─┬─containerd-shim(1836)─┬─registry(1867)─┬─{registry}(1968)
           │                 │                       │                ├─{registry}(1969)
           │                 │                       │                ├─{registry}(1970)
```

Comment: I've killed whatever pid is using port 80, netstat shows no pid using port 80 and I still have the same issue, do I have to check something else?

Comment: @Alaeddine possibly the process which you killed got auto relaunched in which case you need to kill off its watcher however it would show up on netstat

Comment: this doesn't work (anymore): `netstat: option requires an argument -- p`

Answer (score 14):

If you are running Ubuntu, just run

```
sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 stop
```

Then reload your Docker Image

```
docker reload
```

Answer (score 0):

I found so solution:

```
$ docker stop container_name
$ docker commit container_name image_name
$ docker rm container_name
```

then u can create a new container from the image:

```
$ docker run -d -P --name container_name_the_same_or_new image_name
```

and now works.